# Can't launch android example of Mapbox GL for Android. libmapbox-gl.so is not found

Tags: java, android, exception, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am trying to launch the Mapbox GL example for Android. But there is a problem with it - libmapbox-gl.so is not found. I found the same issue here #859, but there is no solution.

Here is the list of what I've done:
I cloned the repo to my desktop, opened the project in android studio, launched make command - everything was OK, no problems detected.

But when I launched the application on VM (x86) - the first and only exception was "libmapbox-gl.so is not found".

The folder 'android/java/MapboxGLAndroidSDK/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/' does not exist at all in the cloned project.

What should I do? And how far is the mapbox gl from release? Would be great to try its best features :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapbox GL for Android is still in heavy development. Stay tuned for a prepackaged version of it that will solve these problems. Meanwhile, join [the project](http://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native) directly.